# How can I restrict the token length while using CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I do not want terms of length less than 3 or more than say 7.There's a straightforward way of doing this in R , but in Python I am not sure.
I tried this, but still doesn't work

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
regex1 = '/^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$/'
vectorizer = CountVectorizer( analyzer='word',tokenizer= tokenize,stop_words = stopwords,token_pattern  = regex1,min_df= 2, max_df = 0.9,max_features = 2000)
vectorizer1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
```

Tried other regex too -

```
  "^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$"
r'^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$'
```

Comment: Why was it down voted ?Pl explain

Comment: @VivekKumar I don't think that's the problem. If it were there would be error raised

Comment: @rock321987 Yes it may be. But until we get a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how will we decide?

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation of [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), it is provided that default `token_pattern` takes tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters. If you want to change this, pass your own regex

In your case, add `token_pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$"` to the options of `CountVectorizer`

**Edit**

The regex that should be used is `[a-zA-Z]{3,7}`. See Example below -

```
doc1 = ["Elon Musk is genius", "Are you mad", "Constitutional Ammendments in Indian Parliament",\
        "Constitutional Ammendments in Indian Assembly", "House of Cards", "Indian House"]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

regex1 = '[a-zA-Z]{3,7}'
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words = 'english', token_pattern  = regex1)
vectorizer1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc1)

vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

**Results -**

```
{u'ammendm': 0,
 u'assembl': 1,
 u'cards': 2,
 u'constit': 3,
 u'elon': 4,
 u'ent': 5,
 u'ents': 6,
 u'genius': 7,
 u'house': 8,
 u'indian': 9,
 u'mad': 10,
 u'musk': 11,
 u'parliam': 12,
 u'utional': 13}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with what I am doing then. Tried all the regex. It still doesnt work

Comment: are you getting 'ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words'? if that is the case, that's the issue with min_df and max_df conditions

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex pattern is wrong here. Its of Javscript. It should be like

```
regex1 = r'^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$'
```

Also I am assuming that the regex should match entire string **NOT** some sub-string. So if a string is like `aaaaabbb cc` should be discarded.

If it doesn't you should use word boundary `\b` instead of start `^` and end `$` anchors. So it should be

```
regex1 = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,7}\b'
```

Here is a working example

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
regex1 = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,7}\b'
token_dict = {123: 'horses', 345: 'ab'}
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern  = regex1)
vectorizer1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(token_dict.values())

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

**Output**

```
['horses']
```

Comment: @Indi what's the error? you should also add data from `token_dict`

Comment: I dont get any error, but I see that tokens like 'yr' and 'ar' appear in tthe dtm. token_dict contains the tokens and their count

Comment: @Indi are you using the regex written in answer *not yours*? I suppose you aren't. Can you check

Comment: @Indi also is `token_dict` key-value pair like `{token: count}` or is it `{count: token}`

Comment: Im sorry token_dict is of the form {<docID> : <text>}

Comment: @Indi can you run the above code and see if it works? If it runs then run it on your main input